# select from a set of pairs in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

## The Problem

I want to do a join with the sense of "and these two columns are represented in this list of possible values *or a neighbour of one of those values*".

## Background

I have a table, call it GTT, in postgresql that is conceptually a map between `(g, t)` pairs:

```
((g1, t1), (g2, t2))
```

Think of this as representing a directed graph (which it is, but that's not how it's primarily used).

Other tables have `g` and `t` columns, and a common query is to do something like this:

```
SELECT g, t, a, b, c
FROM T
WHERE ...;
```

These queries are generated by code, so it sometimes happens that we end up with

```
SELECT g, t, a, b, c
FROM T
WHERE ...
  AND ((g = G1 AND t = T1) OR (g = G2 AND t = T2));
```

Those lists of `(Gi, Ti)` pairs (constants in the query) can get long, but not too long, but nothing in the universe guarantees that they won't grow with time.

## Back to the Problem

I want to add to that constraint that the `(g, t)` values is one of the `(Gi, Ti)` *or* a neighbour of one of them.

If I had only `G` and `T`, I could do something like this:

```
SELECT g, t, a, b, c
FROM T
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT g1 g, t1 t
     FROM GTT
     WHERE g2 = G AND t2 = T
    UNION
     SELECT g2 g, t2 t
     FROM GTT
     WHERE g1 = G and t1 = T) TT
  ON T.g = TT.g AND T.t = TT.t
WHERE ...;
```

I don't see how to do this with multiple `(Gi, Ti)` pairs without repeating the two GTT queries for each pair.

Is there a good way to do this?

## Example

Suppose that GTT contains, among other rows, the following data:

```
1    2    3    4
5    6    3    4
```

Then if `G = 3` and `T = 4`, the original query would catch rows in `T` of the form

```
3    4    a1    b1    c1
3    4    a2    b2    c2
3    4    a3    b3    c3
```

but with the join to pick up neighbours, we'd also catch rows like

```
1    2    a4    b4    c4
5    6    a5    b5    c5
```

The tricky part (to me) is what if instead of having `(G, T) = (3, 4)` we have `(G, T) in ((3, 4), (7, 8), (10, 12))`?

Comment: Please add some (fake) data and the desired result to your question. And maybe define *neighbour* too.

Comment: When I said that GTT is a directed graph, I think I defined neighbour. ;-)

Comment: Without column names it is hard/impossible to understand.

Answer (score 1):

This query solved the problem:

```
SELECT  mt.g, mt.t, mt.a, mt.b, mt.c
FROM main_table mt
INNER JOIN
  (
   SELECT g, t
   FROM (VALUES (1, 2)) as TB(g, t)
  UNION
   SELECT  g1 g, t1 t
   FROM GTT
   WHERE (g1, t1) in ((G1, T1), (G2, T2))
  UNION
   SELECT  g2 g, t2 t
   FROM GTT
   WHERE (g1, t1) in ((G1, T1), (G2, T2))
  ) TT
ON TT.g = mt.g AND TT.t = mt.t;
```